# Is it possible to set up Atom with additional directories, say for Boost files?

Tags: c++, boost, path, include, atom-editor

I've just started using the Atom editor, and tried setting up a simple C++ file to test it out.

Tried to #include a boost file, but got an error that the path couldn't be found. Had to use the absolute path in order to properly include the directories.

**Is there a better way of adding my boost folder?** Tried setting up a environment path for it but couldn't use it with #include. As a hail-mary I tried adding the boost path to my PATH, but still nothing.

The top of my .cpp file:

```
#include <C:\Program Files\Boost\boost_1_73_0\boost\beast\websocket.hpp> //how I currently have to do it
#include <{BOOST_PATH}\boost\beast\websocket.hpp>                        //how I was hoping to do it
```

Still very new to Atom and C++, any help is very appreciated.

E:

Tried the suggestions with not much work, though got it to somewhat work using the -I flag for GCC compilation. Having issues with an error *undefined reference to `__imp_WSACleanup'* but it's too late for that now. Cheers for the help.

Comment: I don't know too much about Atom, but usually this is something that should be configurable by the search-path settings in whatever plugin you use for parsing C++

Comment: You have to add body to your include path and to your library path. Additionally you should add it to the atom search path so that editor features like code completion work.